# MySQL query to extract multiple Lat/Long coordinates and plot on Google map

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query below. I'm trying to pull out the four sets of coordinates, then plot them on my custom Google v3 API page. (I also need it to "connect" the dots with blue lines as well)

### Here is what the original "printable_text" column data looks like:

```
Grids  : T04SR08W09NW

BestFit: 38.204326/-89.995942 38.204330/-89.993452
       : 38.203490/-89.993451 38.203486/-89.995941
PreMark: NO        Directional Boring: NO      Depth>7Ft: NO
```

### Here is my current MySQL query:

```
SELECT ticket
     , SUBSTR(printable_text
             , LOCATE('BestFit: ',printable_text)+9
             , LOCATE('PreMark:', printable_text) - LOCATE('BestFit: '
             , printable_text) - 9) AS coord
     , REPLACE((SUBSTR(printable_text
                      , LOCATE('BestFit: ',printable_text)+9
                      , LOCATE('PreMark:', printable_text) - LOCATE('BestFit: '
                      , printable_text) - 9)),'/',',') AS coord
  FROM tickets 
 WHERE ticket = 'A3041073'
```

### Here is what I have extracted so far:

```
38.204326/-89.995942 38.204330/-89.993452       : 38.203490/-89.993451 38.203486/-89.995941
38.204326,-89.995942 38.204330,-89.993452       : 38.203490,-89.993451 38.203486,-89.995941
```

I'm guessing I need to get rid of the "/", "spaces", "colons", and feed the four coordinates to my Google API for plotting and connecting..?

Comment: You know both columns have the same alias, right?

Comment: right, I was just experimenting.. trying to grab the 4 coordinates so I can use them in a URL string.. Is it possible to "paste" a string of lat/long coordinates into my Google map string..?

Here is a sample of what I'm doing right now with a single set:
gmap_draggable_latlon.cfm?id3=loc:+37.72565&id4=-89.21726%20&z=17

Comment: Using this sample url gets me close to what I'm needing:
--------------------------------------------------------
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|38.204326,-89.995942|38.204330,-89.993452|38.203490,-89.993451|38.203486,-89.995941&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false

But need a regular map, not static.. and need the lat/long values from the query..